# Swift : My files in Firebase Storage wouldn't be deleted

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've got an application which allow user to save some picture on firebase Storage.

I'm trying to allow user to delete this files from the app, and so also to delete it from the storage.

My code :

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser{

                // user is connect

                let storRef = Storage.storage().reference()
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


                storRef.child("Planes").child(userID!).child(dataME[indexPath.row].image).delete(completion: nil)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

                dataME.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            }else{

                fatalError("⛔️ error ...")
            }
```

Now in this case the line in my tableView is totally deleted with the other part of my code the database references is also deleted but the storage doesn't erase the picture ... Why ?

Thank's a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get error when you delete storage

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Planes").child(userID!).child(dataME[indexPath.row].image)
    storageRef.delete { (error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        // else proceed

    }
```

Comment: This error appears : ` "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"
  }`

Comment: This means your file does not exists. Are you saving the file path in database when you upload image? Also check if we are pointing to correct storage reference while deleting the image.

Comment: I've been add the URL to the database and I call it from the database to delete the file.. I'll try to add a breakpoint to see which value is in storRef at this moment.

Comment: ok. check using breakpoint. Also share a screenshot of your storage if possible

Comment: maybe a reason : `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002` I'll try to give you a screenshot, The break point ton give any informations ... I'll send a screenshot too

Comment: Is this added to your info.plist file
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184699/discussion-between-yogesh-tandel-and-flyer74).

Answer (score 0):

You should not search by image. 
Instead try using download URL that firebase supply

you can get the URL from the firebase dashboard by clicking on storage and than clicking on the current image, there you can see the download image.

when you upload an image it returns callback with URL, you have to save the URL on your data structure

upload image example:

```
func uploadImagePic(img1 :UIImage){
        var data = NSData()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img1!, 0.8)! as NSData
        // set upload path
        let filePath = "\(userid)" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        self.storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{
                //store downloadURL
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
                data[index].downloadURL = downloadURL
            }
        }

    }

    // delete example
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let url = data[index].downloadURL
    let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: url)

        storageRef.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                // File deleted successfully
            }
        }
```